# How to enable Thread Safety on Apache2 server

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, pthreads, debian

I am trying to enable Thread Safety on my Apache2 server to ultimately be able to use the PHP pthreads module (PHP multithreading).

So far I compiled PHP from source with options (under `COMMON_CONFIG`) :

```
--enable-maintainer-zts
```

and phpinfo says `Thread Safety     disabled`

Then I recompiled with :

```
--enable-maintainer-zts
--enable-roxen-zts
```

and phpinfo says `Thread Safety     disabled`

Finally I tried with :

```
--enable-maintainer-zts
--enable-roxen-zts
--with-tsrm-pthreads
```

and phpinfo says `Thread Safety     disabled`

I still tried to install pthreads as a last case scenario, using pecl. After moving the `pthreads.so` in the correct CLI rep, PHP says :

```
~ # php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pthreads.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pthreads.so: undefined symbol: sapi_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
```

What am I doing wrong ? Do I need to compile Apache from source using special ./configure options ?

Any intel greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is no need to recompile Apache. I enabled Thread Safety 3 days ago with --enable-maintainer-zts and it works fine. Pthreads can be also compiled into PHP but you have to download it first from GIT. Are you sure you use the correct build [Path, ...]?

Comment: I successfully built everything about 2 weeks ago but was too lazy to update my post :p What I did is compile from PHP.net/Apache.org sources instead of `apt-get source`. Then with the right `./configure` options everything went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything went fine by downloading sources from Apache.org and PHP.net. Then using the right `./configure` options successfully enabled Zend Thread Safety PHP-side and the Worker MPM Apache-side.

If you need info on the `./configure` options please comment.

Note : building PHP and Apache packages via `apt-get source` didn't work for me. Even by editing the `debian/rules` files with required configure options. The packages would install but not taking account for `--enable-maintainer-zts` and `--with-mpm=Worker`.

Comment: can you please guide how to do that... thanx in advance

Comment: It's been 2 years not sure anymore. What I am sure of is download php sources from php.net and Apache sources from Apache.org. Then add option --enable-maintainer-zts and compile.

Comment: i tried everything but it isn't working... i don't know what am i doing wrong.